# PJSIP ndk configuration issue in centos

Tags: android, c, linux, android-ndk, pjsip

I am trying to use pjSip for my android application and following pjsip instructions. My system configurations are centos 7.4 64 bit .
    I have downloaded latest ndk and pjsip code.
    But when I am running the commands I am getting below error.
One more thing I noticed, confige.log aslo showing 
cc1: warning: command line option '-frtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C

```
[root@localhost pjproject-2.7.1]# ./configure-android

configure-android: APP_PLATFORM not specified, using android-27
configure-android: TARGET_ABI not specified, using armeabi
configure-android: calling ./configure with env vars:
 CC = /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
 CXX = /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++
 CFLAGS =  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -I/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -I/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include
 CXXFLAGS =  -shared --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -fexceptions -frtti
 LDFLAGS =  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -L/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/
 LIBS = -lgnustl_static  -lc -lgcc
 AR = /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
 RANLIB = /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
 TARGET_HOST = arm-linux-androideabi
 TARGET_ABI = armeabi
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking target system type... arm-unknown-linux-androideabi
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89... unsupported
checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
checking whether /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ accepts -g... yes
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib... /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ranlib
checking for arm-linux-androideabi-ar... /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ar
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... no
checking for puts in -lwsock32... no
checking for puts in -lws2_32... no
checking for puts in -lole32... no
checking for puts in -lwinmm... no
checking for puts in -lsocket... no
checking for puts in -lrt... no
checking for sin in -lm... yes
checking for uuid_generate in -luuid... no
checking for uuid_generate in -luuid... (cached) no
checking for library containing gethostbyname... none required
Setting PJ_M_NAME to arm
checking memory alignment... 4 bytes (default)
checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
aconfigure: error: in `/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/pjproject-2.7.1':
aconfigure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details

Below is my configue.log result.



    aconfigure:2916: /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -v >&5
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/lto-wrapper
Target: arm-linux-androideabi
.......................................
aconfigure:3269: /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -c -g  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -fexceptions -frtti conftest.c >&5
cc1: warning: command line option '-frtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
aconfigure:3269: $? = 0
aconfigure:3279: result: yes
aconfigure:3296: checking for /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc option to accept ISO C89
aconfigure:3359: /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -c  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -I/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -I/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -fexceptions -frtti conftest.c >&5
cc1: warning: command line option '-frtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
conftest.c:10:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
aconfigure:3359: $? = 1
aconfigure: failed program was:
 /* confdefs.h */
 #define PACKAGE_NAME "pjproject"
 #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pjproject"
 #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.x"
 #define PACKAGE_STRING "pjproject 2.x"
 #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
 #define PACKAGE_URL ""
 /* end confdefs.h.  */
 #include <stdarg.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 struct stat;
 /* Most of the following tests are stolen from RCS 5.7's src/conf.sh.  */
 struct buf { int x; };
 FILE * (*rcsopen) (struct buf *, struct stat *, int);
 static char *e (p, i)
      char **p;
      int i;
 {
  return p[i];
 }
 static char *f (char * (*g) (char **, int), char **p, ...)
 {
  char *s;
   va_list v;
   va_start (v,p);
   s = g (p, va_arg (v,int));
   va_end (v);
  return s;
 }

arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-std'
aconfigure:3359: $? = 1
aconfigure: failed program was:
 /* confdefs.h */
 #define PACKAGE_NAME "pjproject"
 #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pjproject"
 #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.x"
 #define PACKAGE_STRING "pjproject 2.x"
 #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
 #define PACKAGE_URL ""
/* end confdefs.h.  */
 #include <stdarg.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 struct stat;
 /* Most of the following tests are stolen from RCS 5.7's src/conf.sh.  */
 struct buf { int x; };
 FILE * (*rcsopen) (struct buf *, struct stat *, int);
 static char *e (p, i)
      char **p;
      int i;
{
   return p[i];
 }Satic char *f (char * (*g) (char **, int), char **p, ...)
 {
   char *s;
   va_list v;
   va_start (v,p);
   s = g (p, va_arg (v,int));
   va_end (v);
   return s;
 }
* OSF 4.0 Compaq cc is some sort of almost-ANSI by default.  It has
    function prototypes and stuff, but not '\xHH' hex character constants.
    These don't provoke an error unfortunately, instead are silently treated
    as 'x'.  The following induces an error, until -std is added to get
    proper ANSI mode.  Curiously '\x00'!='x' always comes out true, for an
    array size at least.  It's necessary to write '\x00'==0 to get something
    that's true only with -std.  */
 int osf4_cc_array ['\x00' == 0 ? 1 : -1];

 /* IBM C 6 for AIX is almost-ANSI by default, but it replaces macro parameters
    inside strings and character constants.  */
 #define FOO(x) 'x'
 int xlc6_cc_array[FOO(a) == 'x' ? 1 : -1];

 int test (int i, double x);
 struct s1 {int (*f) (int a);};
 struct s2 {int (*f) (double a);};
 int pairnames (int, char **, FILE *(*)(struct buf *, struct stat *, int), int, int);
 int argc;
 char **argv;
 int
 main ()
 {
 return f (e, argv, 0) != argv[0]  ||  f (e, argv, 1) != argv[1];
   ;
   return 0;
 }
aconfigure:3359: /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Ae -c  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -I/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -I/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -fexceptions -frtti conftest.c >&5
cc1: warning: command line option '-frtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
<command-line>:0:1: error: missing '(' after predicate
conftest.c:10:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
aconfigure:3359: $? = 1
aconfigure: failed program was:
 /* confdefs.h */
 #define PACKAGE_NAME "pjproject"
 #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pjproject"
 #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.x"
 #define PACKAGE_STRING "pjproject 2.x"
 #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
 #define PACKAGE_URL ""
 /* end confdefs.h.  */
 #include <stdarg.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 struct stat;
 /* Most of the following tests are stolen from RCS 5.7's src/conf.sh.  */
 struct buf { int x; };
 FILE * (*rcsopen) (struct buf *, struct stat *, int);
 static char *e (p, i)
      char **p;
      int i;
 {
   return p[i];
 }
| static char *f (char * (*g) (char **, int), char **p, ...)
 {
   char *s;
   va_list v;
   va_start (v,p);
   s = g (p, va_arg (v,int));
   va_end (v);
   return s;
 }

/* OSF 4.0 Compaq cc is some sort of almost-ANSI by default.  It has
    function prototypes and stuff, but not '\xHH' hex character constants.
    These don't provoke an error unfortunately, instead are silently treated
    as 'x'.  The following induces an error, until -std is added to get
    proper ANSI mode.  Curiously '\x00'!='x' always comes out true, for an
    array size at least.  It's necessary to write '\x00'==0 to get something
    that's true only with -std.  */
 int osf4_cc_array ['\x00' == 0 ? 1 : -1];

 /* IBM C 6 for AIX is almost-ANSI by default, but it replaces macro parameters
    inside strings and character constants.  */
 #define FOO(x) 'x'
 int xlc6_cc_array[FOO(a) == 'x' ? 1 : -1];

 int test (int i, double x);
 struct s1 {int (*f) (int a);};
 struct s2 {int (*f) (double a);};
 int pairnames (int, char **, FILE *(*)(struct buf *, struct stat *, int), int, int);
 int argc;
 char **argv;
 int
 main ()
 {
 return f (e, argv, 0) != argv[0]  ||  f (e, argv, 1) != argv[1];
   ;
   return 0;
 }
aconfigure:3359: /root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -Aa -D_HPUX_SOURCE -c  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -I/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/include -I/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/armeabi/include  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -fexceptions -frtti conftest.c >&5
cc1: warning: command line option '-frtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C
<command-line>:0:1: error: missing '(' after predicate
conftest.c:10:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>
                   ^
compilation terminated.
aconfigure:3359: $? = 1
aconfigure: failed program was:
 /* confdefs.h */
 #define PACKAGE_NAME "pjproject"
 #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pjproject"
 #define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.x"
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
 #define PACKAGE_URL ""
 /* end confdefs.h.  */
 #include <stdarg.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 struct stat;
 /* Most of the following tests are stolen from RCS 5.7's src/conf.sh.  */
 struct buf { int x; };
 FILE * (*rcsopen) (struct buf *, struct stat *, int);
 static char *e (p, i)
      char **p;
      int i;
 {
   return p[i];
 }
 static char *f (char * (*g) (char **, int), char **p, ...)
 {
   char *s;
   va_list v;
   va_start (v,p);
   s = g (p, va_arg (v,int));
   va_end (v);
   return s;
 }
|              Syntax error
aconfigure:4534: /lib/cpp  --sysroot=/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/android-ndk-r16b/platforms/android-27/arch-arm -fexceptions -frtti conftest.c
cc1: warning: command line option '-frtti' is valid for C++/ObjC++ but not for C [enabled by default]
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/syslimits.h:7:0,
                 from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/limits.h:34,
                 from conftest.c:13:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/limits.h:168:61: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
 #include_next <limits.h>  /* recurse down to the real one */
                                                             ^
aconfigure:4534: $? = 1
aconfigure: failed program was:
 /* confdefs.h */
  #define PACKAGE_NAME "pjproject"
 #define PACKAGE_TARNAME "pjproject"
#define PACKAGE_VERSION "2.x"
 #define PACKAGE_STRING "pjproject 2.x"
 #define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
 #define PACKAGE_URL ""
#define HAVE_LIBM 1
 #define PJ_M_NAME "arm"
 #define PJ_POOL_ALIGNMENT 4
 /* end confdefs.h.  */
 #ifdef __STDC__
 # include <limits.h>
 #else
 # include <assert.h>
 #endif
           Syntax error
aconfigure:4564: error: in `/root/ROOTSIPFOLDER/pjproject-2.7.1':
aconfigure:4566: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
```

Above error are not addressed any where and I have tried every thing they
have suggested.
 I have followed every step very carefully and now dont know where I am doing   wrong. I have tried the same on centos 6.9 but with no success. Initially I tried same on windows with sygwin what there also I was not able to run in. 
I  wonder I there is some issue with my machine or I am doing some thing wrong 
       Sorry I am not able to format the log. Hope I can get some help over here.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the project's build script is a few revisions out of date: https://github.com/pjsip/pjproject/blob/master/configure-android#L180. The headers moved to a merged tree (rather than per-API and per-arch) in r14 and the deprecated headers were removed in r16.

You might want to try using a [standalone toolchain](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain.html) to build. You might want to try using one of these with the non-android configure script first (standalone toolchains are designed to be dropped into arbitrary autoconf systems that don't support Android themselves), but if that doesn't work then try it with configure-android.

Comment: as mentioned I download the latest code.But again with no success. I am stuck in this big time.. Any help would be great.

Comment: Downloading the latest code won't help if the upstream project is still broken, which it is. Someone needs to fix the build script.

Comment: But I guess other guys are able to implement it on there applications.How they are able to run.I didn't saw much of complaints about this issue..Correct me if I am wrong.